# ansible error for the paloaltonetworks configuration

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

The command is successful in my root account in which installed the paloaltonetworks collections, but when executing in "ansible tower" getting error.

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'paloaltonetworks.panos.panos_op'.
```

The paloaltonetworks.panos collection has installed in the ansible tower. when executing the below playbook getting the error:

```
- name: Systeminfo
  hosts: localhost
  collections:
    - paloaltonetworks.panos
  tasks:
  - name: Get the system info
    panos_op:
      provider: '{{ provider }}'
      cmd: 'show system info'
    register: res

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ res.stdout }}'
```

Error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'paloaltonetworks.panos.panos_op'.
```

Answer (score 1):

From Ansible 2.9, you will need to install the collection with ansible-galaxy:

```sh
ansible-galaxy collection install paloaltonetworks.panos
```

In my case, I also needed to add:

```sh
pip3 install pan-python pandevice
```